# Can I open more than one channel using single Jsch Object?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse-plugin, jsch

I'm having a requirement where I need to open one `SftpChannel` for file transfer and one `exec channel` to execute the commands on remote system.So,Can I open these channels using a single `jsch` object and single `session` object.If I can please give me a small code snippet or please do suggest me is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Include an executable version of your code and you are more likely to receive a completed working snippet.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* have multiple open channels on a single session.

```
  Channel chExec = session.openChannel("exec");
  Channel chSFTP = session.openChannel("sftp");

  chExec.setInputStream(System.in);
  chExec.setOutputStream(System.out);
  chSFTP.setInputStream(System.in);
  chSFTP.setOutputStream(System.out);

  chExec.connect();
  chSFTP.connect();
```

In the above snippet, you would be sending all System input into both channels, which you probably dont want to do, so you will have to create a unique stream for one or both of the Channels.

Also, you could open a channel, use it, close it, then open a new channel, all inside the same session.

Jsch does not automatically close your sessions.  You must explicitly close them.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298279/never-ending-of-reading-server-response-using-jsch/16319567#16319567) for an explanation on closing your channels and sessions.

Comment: Can you have multiple channels of the same type("sftp")?

Comment: @Roland I've tried this, I think it's not allowed to do so. The underlying session received an message(message type = SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE) from the Ubuntu server while I was trying to open the second SFTP channel from the same session.

Comment: @Roland Sorry for the previous incorrect comment. I've took a look at the server side settings and find out why I can't open the second SFTP channel. In fact we can have multiple sftp channels, but it's limited by the server side `MaxSessions` option in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. If the `MaxSessions` is set to 1, then only one channel can be opened.