# JSch Never-ending Input Stream blocks thread

Tags: java, inputstream, jsch

I'm using JSch to pull data from a router, however the way the router's prompt works is preventing me from successfully reading the data.

The flow should go something like this:

```
router>drop_into_privileged_mode
Password: password_entered_here
router#give_me_data
...Data goes here...
router#
```

The problem I'm running into is that since the router drops back to a shell prompt after give_me_data, the `InputStream` never dies. The natural choice would be to run a command like `give_me_data; exit;` or `give_me_data && exit`, but unfortunately the router's operating system doesn't allow me to chain commands like that. Equally frustratingly, the command give_me_data takes so long to run that putting the `exit` command into the OutputBuffer does nothing (as it gets sent while the other command is still running and thus not interpreted).

Is there a way for me to preserve the connects of the InputStream, but kill the connection? If that's possible, then the buffer will have a natural end (as the connection is dead), and I can just copy that to a variable. Alternatively, if there's a way to transfer all information currently present in the stream out, then kill the connection, that would work too.

I've tried the solutions proposed in similar StackOverflow questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298279/never-ending-of-reading-server-response-using-jsch) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902386/how-to-read-jsch-command-output) to no avail.

Additionally, here is the code that I'm currently using (It's a solution I devised that suffers from the same blocking problem):

```
    InputStream in = channel.getInputStream(); //This gets the output from the router
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (true) {
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            if (i < 0) {
                break;
            }
            stringBuffer.append(new String(buffer, "UTF-8"));
        }
        System.out.println("done");

        channel.disconnect();  // this closes the jsch channel

        if (channel.isClosed()) {
            if (in.available() > 0) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
            break;
        }
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A side note. Have you considered to use a third-party Expect-like library for interacting with a remote shell? There is a list of java alternatives here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect#Alternatives. Also I'm happen to be an author of such a library, it is called ExpectIt.

Comment: I was considering it; I'll check out expectit. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov is there a way to reach out to you directly? I have a question regarding ExpectIt.

Comment: please post you question to the google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/java-expectit